# I would like to collect multiple speeches into a data frame

Tags: r, rvest, purrr

I'm trying to collect a large set of presidential speeches from a website to put into a data frame.

The website source is https://www.gov.za/speeches

I would like the data set to include the URL source, the Title of each speech, the date of each speech provided on the website, as well as the actual speech text that was delivered.

The issue I am having is

I would like to collect all the speeches that are returned from the search. So I need to web scrape multiple pages.
I need to ensure that the data frame has all the elements provided on the webpage such as title and date.
As I am a politics student I am only just starting to come to terms with R so please be gentle!

I have tried using a few examples but I am not sure how exactly to apply them to my specific problem. Each time I have entered the blow code all I see is another + symbol. Please see my code below.

```
library(rvest)    
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)




html_source <- "https://www.gov.za/speeches/"


map_df(1:610, function(i) {  

cat(".")

pg <- read_html(sprintf(html_source, i))

data.frame(title=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".views-row-first a")),
           text=html_nodes("td a") %>%
                  html_attr("href"),
           date=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".date-display-single" )),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

}) -> SAspeeches
```

This is what is returned.

> ```
>  Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
>   no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"
> ```

Comment: I believe you have a typo in the `text=` line of your dataframe. It should be `html_nodes(pg, "td a") %>% ...`. See if that fixes things for you.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your comment. I have made this change and the code has now run. However, I seem not to be able to collect the speech texts across multiple returned results.

Comment: What is the new error? Or is it a problem with how it's structured?

Comment: The Data that is returned in not going further than the first page of results.

Comment: Your URL isn't correctly formatted for the subsequent pages. You should be using `html_source <- "https://www.gov.za/speeches?page="`

Comment: Thank you Brian! It seems to be running now.